# Is there a way to list all services historically used on AWS account (excluding cloud trail)

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to find a way to list all services used on AWS account, having 1000s of accounts, I can't use cloud trail. Config only provides data on infrastructure like EC2, lambdas, RDSs, which is a fraction of what I need.

Is there an API or a way to make call preferably using an aggregator of some sort?

I would be interested in simple output like account, what services, when first consumed. Any suggestions?

Why do I need it? We let our app teams to consume number of services and they are gradually whitelisted to consume, we would like to understand how quick these are being utilized since whitelsited.

Comment: Are your accounts part of an AWS Organization, with consolidated billing? Or are they all just random, unassociated accounts?

Comment: Can you tell us more about _WHY_ you wish to do this?

Comment: I need this information to derive business specific metrics, I work in a large organisation

Comment: Yes, but _why_ do they want the information? Are they trying to improve security permissions, manage costs, allocate costs, compare cloud providers, detect unusual behaviour / fraud, etc? If you can tell us more about the reason for needing this data, we might be able to suggest a better option.

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at your AWS bill?  That would be a nice source of all the information as to what services were active on an account.

AWS provides the [AWS Cost Explorer API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/ce-api.html) which would permit you to do this programatically.

Comment: Sorry, corrected question, I need to access this information on weekly basis for 1000s of accounts, not all have enabled cost explorer. Billing and Usage perhaps, but can you do an aggregator to not call 1000 accounts (like with config aggregators)?